# SQL Statement With Time

Tags: mysql, sql

---

Hello
I need to list the shifts that contains this period between 22:00 and 05:00:

```
SELECT * 
FROM shift 
WHERE hourstart>='22:00:00' AND hourend<='05:00:00'
```

How can i do it?

Thank you

Comment: You need to include the date if you are crossing midnight

Comment: my column type is Time

Comment: You still need to work with dates

Comment: What do you mean by "contains this period"? If the shift is from 01:00 to 03:00, should it be included? What if it's from 21:00 to 23:00?

Comment: Yes , both should be included

Comment: Thank you , I needed to work with dates .

Answer (score -1):

Hours start <= 22 and hoursend >=5 or hoursend >=22 or hours start <=5 or hours start >=22